# how to change default image in UIActivityIndicator by SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

In my app activityIndicator is necessary. But, i don't want that default symbol. If i want to replace any other image by using SWIFT means, how can i? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't customize the spinning thing in a UIActivityIndicator. What I suggest is that you make your own indication of activity; for example, use an animated UIImage:

```
let im = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("myImages", duration:1)
```

... and show it (in an image view, probably) as a way of suggesting that activity is occurring.

Comment: var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 50, 50)); // set as you want
        let im = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("act_indi", duration:3)
        imageView.image = im;
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

Comment: Read the docs. You need multiple images to be the frames of the animation.